# Plugins with extensive tests

Tags: tests

What are Craft plugins with extensive (codeception) tests in their repositories? I want to look at working examples. I also know that Craft repo itself and Commerce have tests set up.

Answer (score 3):

[Blitz](https://github.com/putyourlightson/craft-blitz) looks like it has a fairly extensive testing setup.